# php mongo db $in query for multiple keys from DB not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an issue where query fails to work when i use values from `mongoDB` but works when i try static/hard-coded values.
Can you kindly point out what i am not doing correctly ?

When i hard-code the values like below, the code works fine.

```
$customer = $this->mongo->selectCollection('bookings');
$cursor = $customer->find(array('provider_id' => "0", 'cat_id' => array('$in' => array('591d380c227951b706e18a56','591da979227951a10f004ad7','591d42292279517209004ad7'))));
```

but when the values come from mongoDB this query fails to work.

```
$cattype = array();
foreach ($catlist  as $key => $value){ $cattype[] = "'".$value['cid']."'";}
$catlist = implode(',', $cattype);
$customer = $this->mongo->selectCollection('bookings');
$cursor = $customer->find(array('provider_id' => "0", 'cat_id' => array('$in' => array($catlist))));

$catlist = comes from mongoDB
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors:

The first one is in your for each. Instead of adding the id's, you add `'...'`.

```
foreach ($catlist  as $key => $value){
    $cattype[] = $value['cid']
}
```

The second on is in your statement. You want to pass the `$cattype` array, but `$cattype` is already an array, so you wrap it again inside an array.

```
$cursor = $customer->find([
    'provider_id' => "0",
    'cat_id' => ['$in' => $catlist]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use first need to be convert in mongo id, 
It may help you.

```
$cattype = array();
foreach ($catlist  as $key => $value) { 
  $cattype[] = new \MongoId($value['cid']);
}
$catlist = implode(',', $cattype);
$customer = $this->mongo->selectCollection('bookings');
$cursor = $customer->find(array('provider_id' => "0", 'cat_id' => 
array('$in' => array($catlist))));
```

Comment: Thanks your support $value['cid'] not mongoid

Answer (score 0):

```
$cattype = array();
foreach ($catlist  as $key => $value) { 
   $cattype[] = $value['cid'];
}
$catlist = implode(',', $cattype);
$customer = $this->mongo->selectCollection('bookings');
$cursor = $customer->find(array('provider_id' => "0", 'cat_id' => 
      array('$in' => $catlist))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found answer. no need to implode $cattype. just give $cattype in direct inside of $in like array('$in' => array($cattype))